# Listing all available WiFi access points in iOS

Tags: ios, wifi, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to build an iOS application where I'll show the user a list of available WiFi Access Points to the user. First of all, I know that trying to do this will get my Application auto-denied in the App Store and that's okay, I'm only doing this for research purposes.

While I was researching, I found [this GitHub library](https://github.com/ipinak/iOS-WiFi) but it only works for 4.x and 5.x. This topic was also [discussed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8022987/1374416) on how to use the iphone-wireless library but the top answer's link is down. Another answer [linked this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) with a sample project but it seems that it only scans for other devices connected to where your device is currently connected.

I also found [iPhone-Wireless'](https://code.google.com/archive/p/iphone-wireless/) Google Code page but there's no guide whatsoever on how to use it.

Has anyone done this before? Listing all the available WiFi Access Points? I am okay with using libraries that will make the App Store reject my application as I have to plans of distributing it.